# Error 403 wont load any files in project folders

Tags: html

Can someone please explain with clear step by step instructions to a noobie, why is my console giving me these errors for some of my files on a project? I usually get them for external style sheets sometimes images and external .js documents.

Makes no sense to me.

Console shows Error: 403 Forbidden for each of them...

My noobie intuition says something is not right with my permissions for my sites directory or something among these lines. I dont know how to check

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a LAMP stack for web server then you can face that problem.
First check the permission of all the files in the subsequent directory -
Let say that these are four external js in your html file like as :-

```
<script src="/js/file1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/file2.js"></script>
<script src="/js/file3.js"></script>
<script src="/js/file4.js"></script>
```

and you are getting errors for file1.js and file2.js then goto the js directory and check their permissions :-

```
user@host js $ ls -la
total 188
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user  4096 Jul 19 01:51 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 user user  4096 Jul 19 01:39 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  55258 Feb 13  2014 file1.js
-rwxrw-r-- 1 user user  55258 Feb 13  2014 file2.js
-rwxrw-r-- 1 user user  55258 Feb 13  2014 file3.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  55258 Feb 13  2014 file4.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  29110 Feb 13  2014 bootstrap.min.js
```

If required change their permission with **chmod** and **chown** command.